# JavaEE7-hands on lab tutorial -- unable to get the database loaded?

Tags: jakarta-ee, java-ee-7, wildfly-8

I am following the tutorial on `Java EE7`-hands on lab [here](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/javaee-samples/javaee7-hol/blob/master/docs/javaee7-hol.html). I followed the instructions as provided there to set up my `WildFly Application server`. Everything works fine. The tutorial zip comes with sample data and `sql load scripts` that is used to initialize the data-source.  If no data-source is provided in `persistence.xml`, `WildFly` will provide a `default data-source` as mentioned in the tutorial.

At the end of step 3 in the [tutorial link](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/javaee-samples/javaee7-hol/blob/master/docs/javaee7-hol.html), here is how my screen-shot looks like:

[image]

But what is expected (as per [tutorial link](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/javaee-samples/javaee7-hol/blob/master/docs/javaee7-hol.html): Figure 12) is this:

[image]

The difference is "showing movies in theaters!" in my case to "showing 20 movies in 7 theaters!" in expected one. 
The JSF template used to display these numbers makes a EJB call that fetches data from the data-source. Looking at this, I think that my data-source is not initialized. But I don't why since I followed the tutorial word-by-word. I am also having hard trouble-shooting this.

Thanks for help in advance

**EDIT**

the server log shows `Unable to determine H2 database version, certain features may not work.`

```
2014-10-02 18:02:50,167 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.5.Final}
2014-10-02 18:02:50,170 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2014-10-02 18:02:50,172 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2014-10-02 18:02:50,330 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBWS022052: Starting JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.2.4.Final
2014-10-02 18:02:50,491 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) JBAS011409: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service 'movieplex7.war#movieplex7PU'
2014-10-02 18:02:50,641 INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.4.Final}
2014-10-02 18:02:50,875 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2014-10-02 18:02:50,883 WARN  [org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) HHH000431: Unable to determine H2 database version, certain features may not work
2014-10-02 18:02:50,922 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2014-10-02 18:02:51,047 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2014-10-02 18:02:51,048 WARN  [org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) HHH000431: Unable to determine H2 database version, certain features may not work
2014-10-02 18:02:51,055 WARN  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.schemagen.GenerationTargetToDatabase] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) Unable to execute JPA schema generation drop command [DROP TABLE SALES]
2014-10-02 18:02:51,055 WARN  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.schemagen.GenerationTargetToDatabase] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) Unable to execute JPA schema generation drop command [DROP TABLE POINTS]
2014-10-02 18:02:51,055 WARN  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.schemagen.GenerationTargetToDatabase] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) Unable to execute JPA schema generation drop command [DROP TABLE SHOW_TIMING]
2014-10-02 18:02:51,055 WARN  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.schemagen.GenerationTargetToDatabase] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) Unable to execute JPA schema generation drop command [DROP TABLE MOVIE]
2014-10-02 18:02:51,056 WARN  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.schemagen.GenerationTargetToDatabase] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) Unable to execute JPA schema generation drop command [DROP TABLE TIMESLOT]
2014-10-02 18:02:51,056 WARN  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.schemagen.GenerationTargetToDatabase] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) Unable to execute JPA schema generation drop command [DROP TABLE THEATER]
2014-10-02 18:02:51,250 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-8) Initializing Mojarra 2.2.6-jbossorg-4 20140501-1134 for context '/movieplex7'
2014-10-02 18:02:51,867 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS017534: Registered web context: /movieplex7
2014-10-02 18:02:51,905 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) JBAS018559: Deployed "movieplex7.war" (runtime-name : "movieplex7.war")
2014-10-02 18:02:51,910 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
2014-10-02 18:02:51,911 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
2014-10-02 18:02:51,911 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015874: WildFly 8.1.0.Final "Kenny" started in 5525ms - Started 256 of 310 services (91 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

I have also raised an issue in github repo here:
https://github.com/javaee-samples/javaee7-hol/issues/17#issuecomment-57561731

Comment: Assuming you're using Netbeans (as per the tutorial), open up the [output]. There should be a Wildfly Server tab that shows the server log. Do you see any exceptions?

Comment: @peeskillet: I am using Eclipse. but I located the server log. please see edit above where I included server log

Comment: So I got the app, and tried to run it (Netbeans, Wildfly-8.1). It didn't run at all. Problem with the data source not being found. So (with Wildfly started) I went to the admin console `localhost:9990` and typed in my credentials. In the console, Selected the [Configuration] tab, then [Datasources]. There is no `defaultDataSource`. There _was_ a `java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS` as a preconfigured datasource. So in the `persistence.xml`, I changed the data source to that, and it worked. FYI, I ran the `movieplex7` from the `solution` dir from the download

Comment: @peeskillet: Thanks for taking time to test this out. If you look at the github repo linked above, I have a snapshot showing that my defaultDataSource is configured. can you please paste the link that you used in persistence.xml? That will be very helpful..

Comment: This is the only thing I changed to the entire project. Just changed the jndi name for the data source to `<jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS</jta-data-source>`

Comment: great!. worked like a charm. I was always doubting something wrong with datasource, but the tutorial did not say any configuration for datasources. I will issue this concern to them. if you want to post as an answer, I can accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I got the app, and tried to run it (Netbeans, Wildfly-8.1). It didn't run at all. Problem with the data source not being found. So (with Wildfly started) I went to the admin console `localhost:9990` and typed in my credentials. In the console, Selected the [Configuration] tab, then [Datasources]. There is no defaultDataSource. There was a `java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS` as a preconfigured datasource. So in the `persistence.xml`, I changed the data source to that, and it worked. FYI, I ran the movieplex7 from the solution dir from the download

---

This is the only thing I changed to the entire project. Just changed the jndi name for the data source to `<jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS</jta-data-source>`

---

**EDIT**

So @ArunGupta is correct. In the application, in the `persistence.xml` There was this commented out line

```
<!--<jta-data-source>java:comp/DefaultDataSource</jta-data-source>-->
```

I assumed I would have to *uncomment* that. By *uncommenting* it, that's what caused it to initially not work. So I commented it back out, and **without** specifying any data souce i.e. `java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS`, it works as specified. So your problem seems to be elsewhere.

Comment: I tried glassFish with this configuration `<jta-data-source>java:comp/DefaultDataSource</jta-data-source>`. suprisingly this does not work..same issue as I posted for WildFly.

Comment: Take a look at my **EDIT**. So the application does work as expected. Your problem lies elsewhere. Please untick the check mark, until you find out what the problem is/was. Then you can answer your own question once/if you figure it out.

Comment: why is that the first time you tried running, it did not run then?

Comment: Becuase I uncommented the `java:comp/DefaultDataSource`. It seems the server couldn't find _that_ specific data source. I'm not sure if that's the default data source Arun is talking about or if there is an _implicit_ data source that is not visually displayed to us

Comment: in your answer before,you mentioned you added  `<jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS</jta-data-source>` which is the default dataSource for JBoss. Adding that to my persistance.xml worked on wildfly. `java:comp/DefaultDataSource` is the default Datasource of glassFish.

Comment: Again I am not sure, I have never used this _default data source_ Arun is talking about. It appears the `ExampleDS` is _not_ the _"default data source"_ as I am still able to use it without specifying the `ExampleDS`. Or maybe it _is_ the default data source, that Wildfly goes to when we don't explicitly specify a data source. We can wait for an explanation from Arun, if he gets around to it

Comment: Did you try to run it on glassfish, with no data source explicitly specified (i.e. commenting out the data source in the persistence.xml)? Or on Wildfly?

Comment: I think it could be problems with Eclipse JBoss tools. because when I mvn package and deploy manually to WildFly, it works fine. (without DataSource tag in it...)

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
<jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS</jta-data-source>
```

should not be required as Java EE 7 defines a new default data source that should be picked up automatically.

This issue is also being discussed at https://github.com/javaee-samples/javaee7-hol/issues/17.

Comment: You are correct, please see my **EDIT**. Issue is somewhere else for the OP